# how to change the version of an applescript app?

Tags: applescript, version

I have made a simple app and I want to change the version of the app from version 1.0 to version 1.2

[image: My problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience (OS X El Capitan), after editing the file suggested above, you then have to rename your app for the version to change. Alternatively, you can change the name of the app before editing the text file, and then name it what you intended it to be after doing so. Only then will it change from Version 1.0 to whatever you want it to show - note: These instructions are only required to change version listed on the preview (when you click the app and press spacebar), the 'Get info' window changes immediately.

Answer (score 4):

An AppleScript applet has quite the same structure as a normal Cocoa application.

- Right-click on the applet, select `Show Package Contents`, open folder `Contents`
- Open file `Info.plist` with a text editor.
- Update the value of the key `CFBundleShortVersionString` or – if it doesn’t exist – insert

  ```
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>1.2</string>
  ```
- Save the file.

Comment: @samrockw22 if this is working now why isn't this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

In the Script Editor, once you save your app, a sidebar option should pop up allowing you to change the app's version